# Can't give PRIMARY KEY property in POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why doesn't this work exactly?

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.post 
    ALTER COLUMN id TYPE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    OWNER to postgres;
```

The error is

> syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"

Comment: No image links please. It would be so easy for you to copy and paste the code and the error message here.

Comment: Have you read the manual? Does your statement follow the ALTER TABLE syntax?

Comment: Yes, I did. From the official docs: "ALTER TABLE table_name
  ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE column_definition;" and I did that, the problem is that it doesn't understand Primary key for some reason.

Comment: Where in the manual did you find that `primary key` can be used in an alter column like that?

Comment: It's obviously a part of column definition, so it should be written with it.

Comment: No, it's not. And the manual does not indicate that this is correct syntax.

Comment: So, what's the correct syntax, mr. a horse with no name?

Comment: For what? Changing the data type or defining a primary? See [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)  for the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for PostgreSQL is as follows :

Try with this:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.post 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Documentation : https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-primary-key/